# Hosts file update Yosemite

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, hosts

I am running OSX Yosemite 10.10.2

When I update the hosts file using nano or vi with sudo, the update to hosts file gets reverted after a restart. I am new to Mac. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong. Obviously I searched the internet before asking this question and I don't think I found a good answer. Apologize if it is a repeat question.

Comment: Which hosts file exactly are you updating where?

Comment: I am updating /private/etc/hosts

Comment: You should be editing `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: I tried that and after a restart, my entry in the hosts file vanishes. Not sure what I am doing wrong here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to retain the hosts file entry by updating the /etc/hosts.ac in addition to /etc/hosts

I noticed that during logon and while connecting to work network via VPN the hosts file was replaced with the contents from /etc/hosts.ac