# Error with weblogic and coherence on OSX when on VPN

Tags: macos, weblogic, vpn, oracle-coherence

I am running OSX Yosemite on my Mac. I am working on application that runs on weblogic and uses coherence.

I was able to setup weblogic & coherence and everything works when I am at work. When I try the same setup at home connecting via VPN to the work network I face issues.
The issues is that my weblogic server cannot talk to the coherence server.

a) My first issue is that I cannot update my hosts file to be permanent. It just vanishes after a restart. I have posed this as a seperate question in SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29125838/hosts-file-update-yosemite)

b) I think my problem is that my ports are not open. when weblogic tries to connect to localhost on port 8088 it just hangs there for a long time and then gives up throwing a timeout exception.

c) When I try port scan under network utility I see that the ports that weblogic/coherence uses is open when on work network but closed when I am on VPN.

What should I do to open those ports? Is it on the wireless router that I should open the ports or on the VPN client?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by upgrading my VPN client - Cisco Anyconnect 4.X version.